# Grails org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException for simultaneous requests

Tags: database, multithreading, hibernate, grails

I have an app with a controller. Doing an action of the controller does an update with database fields. When the actions are done one at a time, it works ok. But when I do two actions simultaneously, I get the `org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException` error

```
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
```

I need the controller to be able to handle simultaneous actions, for example by queuing the requests and doing them sequentially. Is that somehow possible? Or do I need to take care of it somehow myself?

(Would using `synchronized` help here? Is it the *correct* way?)

The database is mem/file, as I do only little work with it. It is not necessary to run a full-scale database.

EDIT: the calling 'hierarchy' is as follows:

This is the entry point - controller.

```
GameController
  def doTurn() {
    String login = params.login


    // From stackoverflow
    def c = Player.createCriteria()
    def player = c.get {
        eq "login", login
        lock true
    }

    // def player = Player.findAllByLogin(login).get(0)
    PlayerChoice choice = Utils.intToChoice(Integer.parseInt(params.choice))
    int turnNumber = Integer.parseInt(params.turn)

    gameFlowService.makeTurn(player, choice, turnNumber)

    def res = new Utils().playerStateToJSON(player)
    render res as JSON
  }
```

It calls gameFlowService:

```
GameFlowService{
  def makeTurn(Player player, PlayerChoice choice, int turnNumber) {
   (...)
    Game currentGame = player.currentGame
    Turn lastTurn = currentGame.getLastTurn()
    // I do stuff with Turn (if it exists) or create it
      currentGame.createTurn()
      currentGame.getLastTurn().makeChoice(player, choice)
    if (currentGame!=null){
        currentGame.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    }
}
```

Game:

```
Game {
  Player player1
  Player player2

  int turnsToBePlayed

  List turns
  static hasMany = [turns: Turn]
  static belongsTo = [tournament: Tournament]

  public void createTurn() {
    Turn turn = new Turn([game      : this,
                          turnNumber: turns.size(),
                          player1   : player1,
                          player2   : player2,
                          choice1   : PlayerChoice.CHOICE_NOT_SET,
                          choice2   : PlayerChoice.CHOICE_NOT_SET,
                          points1   : 0,
                          points2   : 0])

    this.addToTurns(turn)
    this.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
  }
}
```

And Turn:

```
class Turn {
    int turnNumber
    boolean completed = false

    Player player1
    Player player2

    PlayerChoice choice1
    PlayerChoice choice2

    int points1
    int points2

    static belongsTo = [game: Game]

    public void makeChoice(Player player, PlayerChoice playerChoice){
      // This method only changes Turn's member variables
    }
}
```

I only save the Game instance when I add a new turn to it - I was led to believe that Hibernate automatically persists any further changes.

Despite using lock, I still get the same error (stacktrace says it happens on line in Game: `this.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)`)

**EDIT 2:**
I believe my problem is not that uncommon. Controller actions lead to changes in the database, and that needs to be serialized, somehow. How does Hibernate/Grails solve it?

Comment: show some COOOOOOODDDDDEEEEE!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is as follows, considering 2 simultanous threads accessing the databse:

1. A retrieves object
2. B retrieves object
3. A updates object
4. A saves object
5. B updates object
6. B saves object -> StaleObjectStateException

It is possible to lock the object when retrieving it from your database. This results in a "select ... for update", see this link for usage:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/lock.html

But in order to avoid any race conditions, you have to use the lock method as your getter, like this:

```
def airport = Airport.lock(10) // lock for update
airport.name = "Heathrow"
airport.save()
```

If you have to query the object, you can use lock inside a Criteria.

This in a example for Criteria:

```
def c = Airport.createCriteria()
c.get {
  eq "name", name
  lock true
}
```

Comment: does the lock apply to the whole domain hierarchy? e.g. I retrieve a Player object from the database, it owns a Game object and that in turn owns a Turn object. Do all 3 get locked (because I might update them all)?

Comment: I retrieve the object like so `def player = Player.findAllByLogin(login).get(0)` .. is it enough to call `player.lock()` afterwards, or not?

Comment: why don't you use `Player.findByLogin login`?

Comment: `lock()` has nothing to do with your problem. it locks the instance only within the current hibernate session.

Comment: Calling lock after a get might lead to problems, since there is a time between retrieving the object and locking it. You can query for an object with a Criteria and use "lock true" inside the Criteria. And it does not only lock the object inside the session, here is what the Hibernate docu says about it: __An upgrade lock. Objects loaded in this lock mode are materialized using an SQL select ... for update.__

Comment: I added code that is executed. Sadly, I still get the same error, even using criteria

Comment: Now I am getting the `StaleObjectStateException` when calling `game.lock()`. I wonder, does Grails handle waiting for releasing the lock, or does it just throw an exception in my face and I have to deal with it myself?

Comment: Try it with Game.lock(id). If you call lock() on your object instance, it might already be to late.